# Add new blank row in CellBeginEdit Event

Tags: c#, datagridview, window

My `DataGridView` is binded by a `DataTable` and it is set to Enable Adding.

In `CellBeginEdit` event, I add value to a cell of new row with cell-value of upper row.Like this-

```
 private void dgGrid_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
dgGrid[intCol, intLastRow].Value = dgGrid[intCol, intLastRow-1].Value;
}
```

Whether I can set value to new cell, but there is no new row automatically appear at the below.
 When I  type something in this cell, new row will automatically appeared,but I want to display new blank row at the below before typing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take alook at this link below. I'm not sure you can get round this.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/27624ce6-1c84-4e65-8ba7-fc5a8a3e1ec8